How to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{2-x^2}} , dx$?
I'm trying to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx$ and I'm encountering some difficulties. Here's what I have tried so far:
I used the substitution $x = \sqrt{2} \sin(\theta)$, which transforms the integral into: $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\sqrt{2} \sin(\theta))  d\theta.$
This further breaks down into: $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left(\ln(\sqrt{2}) + \ln(\sin(\theta)) \right)d\theta.$
This splits into two integrals: $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\sqrt{2})d\theta + \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\sin(\theta))d\theta.$
The first part evaluates to: $\frac{\pi}{8} \ln(2)$. The second part uses a known result: $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\sin(\theta))d\theta = -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln(2)$.
Combining these, I get: $\frac{\pi}{8} \ln(2) - \frac{\pi}{4} \ln(2) = -\frac{\pi}{8} \ln(2)$. Numerically, this result evaluates to approximately $-0.273$, but I expect the result to be around $-0.73$ based on numerical methods. Could someone help identify where my evaluation might be going wrong, or confirm the correct method to approach this integral?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

your mathematical formulas are unreadable. This site uses mathjax, I bet there is a page to look that up

$$\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right) = -\log\left(2\right)-\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(2kx\right)}{k} ,\quad\left(0 <x < \pi\right)$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\sin \theta) d \theta 
= & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \left(\frac{e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}}{2 i}\right) d \theta \\
= & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\ln \left[e^{\theta i}\left(1-e^{-2 \theta i}\right)\right]-\ln 2-\ln i\right) d \theta\\
= & -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\Re \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \left(1-e^{-2 \theta i}\right) d \theta \\
= & -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\Re\left(\frac{1}{-2 i} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln \left(1-e^{-2 \theta i}\right)}{e^{-2 \theta i}} d\left(e^{-2 \theta i}\right)\right] \\
= & -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\Re\left[\frac{1}{2 i} \operatorname{Li_2}  \left(e^{-2 \theta i}\right)\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \\
= & -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\Re\left[\frac{1}{2 i}\left(\operatorname{Li_2} (-i)-\operatorname{Li_2} (1)\right)\right] \\
= & -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\Re\left[\frac{1}{2 i}\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{48}-i G\right)\right] \\
= & -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2-\frac{G}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \sqrt{2} d \theta+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\sin \theta) d \theta \\
& =\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2 -\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2-\frac{G}{2} \\
& =-\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2-\frac{1}{2} G
\end{aligned}
$$
where $G$ is the Catalan’s constant.


The integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln(\sin(\theta)) \mathrm{d}\theta$ does not equal $-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln(2)$ but instead $-\frac{G}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln(2)$ with Catalan's constant G. To get this result you can follow the steps here.

You should include reasoning for that claim.

With a few substitutions we can unveil two well-known integrals; see here and here.
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{2-x^2}} \, dx \\
&= \frac14 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx & x\to\sqrt{1-x} \\
&= \frac14 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \log(1-\sin x) \, dx & x\to\sin x \\
&= \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\log\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}}{1+x^2} \, dt & x\to2\arctan x \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{1+x^2} \, dx - \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\log\left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} \, dx \\
&= \left(\frac\pi8\log2 - G\right) - \frac12 \left(\frac\pi2\log2 - G\right) \\
&= \boxed{- \frac\pi8 \log2 - \frac G2}
\end{align*}$$
Alternatively, after the step $x\to2\arctan x$, putting $x\to\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$ replaces one of the former log integral with a simpler one,
$$I = \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\log\left(2x^2\right) - \log\left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} \, dx \\
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log\left(2x^2\right)}{1+x^2} \, dx &= \frac\pi4 \log2 + 2 \sum_{n\ge0} (-1)^n \int_0^1 x^{2n} \log x \, dx \\
&\!\stackrel{\rm IBP}= \frac\pi4 \log2 - 2 \underbrace{\sum_{n\ge0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}}_{=G} \end{align*} \\
\implies I = \frac12 \left(\frac\pi4 \log2 - 2G - \frac\pi2\log2 + G\right) = -\frac\pi8 \log2 - \frac G2$$
